# Handlebars: display different HTML tags using IF statements

Tags: if-statement, compiler-errors, handlebars.js

The partial:

```
<h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}<ul>{{else}}<div>{{/if~}}
    {{~#each stores~}}
       {{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}<li>{{/if~}}
           {{> address-partial }}
       {{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}</li>{{/if~}}
    {{~/each~}}
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}</ul>{{else}}</div>{{/if~}}
```

The error:

```
Error: Unable to find closingIf after {"name":"openingIf","value":"@root.config.isMobile"}. (token: 31)
    at findClosingTokenInner (filename:3600:8)
    at findClosingToken (filename:3635:16)
```

After removing the tildes from the first and last lines -- same error.

After removing all tildes from the code -- same error.

After removing everything except the first and last lines -- new error:

```
Error: Unable to find closingTag after {"name":"openingTag","value":"ul"}. (token: 26)
    at findClosingTokenInner (filename:3600:8)
    at findClosingToken (filename:3635:16)
```

This works perfectly:

```
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile~}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {{~#each stores~}}
           <li>
               {{> address-partial }}
           </li>
        {{~/each~}}
    </ul>
{{~else~}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <div>
        {{~#each stores~}}
           {{> address-partial }}
        {{~/each~}}
    </div>
{{~/if~}}
```

You can see how much longer this is now, and I am repeating almost all of the information. Is there no way to make the original code work with handlebars, or am I missing something (probably really simple...)?

Also, if you can explain **why** this problem is a thing, I will be eternally grateful.

Thank you!!!

Comment: **`<h2>` should not be a child of `<ul>`**. UL and OL can only contain intermixed `<li>` elements, `<template>` elements, and `<script>` elements.

Comment: @chharvey, that's entirely beside the point, but thank you for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code into the [sandbox](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) with v4.0.3 selected and it runs without any compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a test snippet of your methods and the same methods without ~. All are working and I did no modification except removing ~ on the methods 3 and 4. Try using a newer version of handlebar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = {
    "config" : { "isMobile": true }, 
    "regionName": "Region1", 
    "stores" : [ 
        {"name":"store1", "address":"address1"},
        {"name":"store2", "address":"address2"},
        {"name":"store3", "address":"address3"}
        ]
  };
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#*inline "address-partial"}}
  {{name}} - {{address}}
{{/inline}}
Method 1 : ~ + compact
<h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}<ul>{{else}}<div>{{/if~}}
    {{~#each stores~}}
       {{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}<li>{{/if~}}
           {{> address-partial }}
       {{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}</li>{{/if~}}
    {{~/each~}}
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile}}</ul>{{else}}</div>{{/if~}}
Method 2 : long + ~
{{~#if @root.config.isMobile~}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {{~#each stores~}}
           <li>
               {{> address-partial }}
           </li>
        {{~/each~}}
    </ul>
{{~else~}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <div>
        {{~#each stores~}}
           {{> address-partial }}
        {{~/each~}}
    </div>
{{~/if~}}
Method 3 : no ~ + long
{{#if @root.config.isMobile}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <ul>
        {{#each stores}}
           <li>
               {{> address-partial }}
           </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{else}}
    <h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
    <div>
        {{#each stores}}
           {{> address-partial }}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
Method 4 : no ~ + compact
<h2>{{regionName}}</h2>
{{#if @root.config.isMobile}}<ul>{{else}}<div>{{/if}}
    {{#each stores}}
       {{#if @root.config.isMobile}}<li>{{/if}}
           {{> address-partial }}
       {{#if @root.config.isMobile}}</li>{{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{#if @root.config.isMobile}}</ul>{{else}}</div>{{/if}}
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```